# How to highlight points on heat map

Tags: plotting

If I have for example a heat map:

```
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1.0, 2.0}, {y, -1.0, 1.0},ColorFunction ->ColorData["SunsetColors"], PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

and I want to highlight a particular point $(x,y)$ on the 2D place where the heat map is shown (for example with a red dot), how can I do that? Also is it possible to highlight many points and connect them by a line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use Epilog:

```
RedPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}];
WhiteLine = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}];
DensityPlot[
  x^2 + y^2, {x, -1.0, 2.0}, {y, -1.0, 1.0}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
  PlotLegends -> True, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[RedPoints], White, Line[WhiteLine]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Graphics` primitives in `Plot` by using the `Epilog` or `Prolog` Option.

```
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1.0, 2.0}, {y, -1.0, 1.0},  
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
   PlotLegends -> True,  
   Epilog -> {
              Red, 
              PointSize[0.02], 
              Point[{1, 0}], 
              Green,
              Arrow[{{1.5, 0}, {1.04, 0}}]
              }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I draw a red point at the origin, a line between random points as well as a shortest tour between the same points shown in yellow.

```
orig = {0, 0};
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1.5}, {10, 2}];
st = FindShortestTour[pts];
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1.0, 2.0}, {y, -1.0, 2.0}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], PlotLegends -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@orig
   , Line@pts, Yellow, Point@pts
   , Green
   , Line@pts[[Last@st]]
   }
 ]
```

[image]